# Regexp to validate copyrights

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm creating a series of filters in order to validate strings containing copyrights and I'm struggling to find the appropriate regexp to match them.

Strings can come in two ways:

```
// Copyright (c) YYYY - 2015.
// Copyright (c) 2015.
```

*YYYY can refer to any digit

I am planning to use re.match() however if you have any better suggestion I'd appreciate it as well.

Comment: Do you care about the value of the year? Minimum of 2000 or something? If not I think `// Copyright \(c\) (\d{4}\s*-\s*)?\d{4}` would do it (also escape `/` if that is delimiter).

Comment: The value of the first year is not really that important, it only has to be 4 digits long. The second year though, will always be the current year, so it would be great to tweak the solution in order to get that value from a variable maybe.

Comment: You should be able to make that a variable than and just concatenate it to the regex. I don't know python though so can't say how to do that. In php it'd be something like `preg_match('~// Copyright \(c\) (\d{4}\s*-\s*)?' . $year . '~',`. `preg_match` is the function that checks for a regex match and the `~` are the delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
import datetime, re
reg = re.compile(r'//\s*Copyright\s*\(c\)\s*([0-9]{4})(?:\s*\-\s*%d)?\.' % datetime.date.today().year, re.I)
reg.match('// copyright (c) 1997 -   2015').group(1)  # 1997
```

Please note I'm not using `\d` because it matches a wide range of Unicode numeral digits that are not 0-9.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I'll be choosing it as an answer based on completeness. @buckley also provided a good answer but I'll choose yours over his

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
// Copyright \(c\) \d{4}( - \d{4})?.
```

Comment: Thank you! However the second \d{4} will always match to the current year (2015 and so on). Is there any way to specify that through a variable where I could store the year previously and try to match it?

Comment: @pabloxrl That's what I have done in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32010038/180709).

Comment: @pabloxrl You can't get hold of a the current year in a pure regex way. Resort to your programming language to make the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is copyright format. If you bound conditions to the only two lines in your answer, then it's easy, as shown in answers above.

But if you try to go deeper, you will face multiple issues. Let's reformulate task to: "For a given copyright string A define whether A represents valid copyright line or not".

At first, we should notice that according to [US Copyright law](http://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ03.pdf) if you use copyright notice (note that it's not required!) then you should use all three of following:

1. Copyright symbol, or "Copyright" word, or short version "Copr."
2. The year of first publication (or several years). So all of those are valid years: "2015", "2010-2015", "2005, 2009, 2010-2013, 2015"
3. The name of the copyright owner.

And these three may go in any order, in fact. I assume that in full form it's almost impossible to solve this task using regexp. But even if you bound years to one or two separated with dash, it will be still very complicated regexp.

Secondly, even if you had written "perfect copyright detector", when you will apply it to the files\lines you want to check, if will be surprised. Because if you're checking not a couple of files\lines, but tens of thousands, you will see that often content creators do not care much about the format. Starting from easy issues like do not using copyright holder name ("Copyright (C) 2015") and up to using additional notice ("All rights reserved."), changing case for letters ("copyright" or "Copyright"), different years writing ("2010 2015" w\o dash, "(2010)(2015)" OMG, "2010 - 2015" with extra spaces etc.) and many other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach would be:

import re

re_copyright = re.compile(r'copyright (([Cc@])|\d+).*', re.IGNORECASE)
re_copyright.match(text)

The above regular expression should work to fetch any copyright notices from the text variable.